# Logging HTTPRequest NSUTF8Encoding

Tags: ios, nsutf8encoding

When trying to debug a NSURLRequest with POST data I use this to write to my log:

```
NSLog(@" Body: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlRequest.HTTPBody encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

Which outputs the data like so:

```
Body: add_contact=%7B%0A%20%20%22ENTITY_DATE%22%20%3A%201484141409.066969%2C%0A%20%20%22ENTITY_PAYLOAD%22%20%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22SYNC_GUID%22%20%3A%20%22B656614A-C79F-4130-93D0-3CE84E4D3EC2-14296-0000380ED36B1B76%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22VDM%22%20%3A%20%22%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22FAX%22%20%3A%20%22%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22LAST_NAME%22%20%3A%2...
```

How can I clean this string up to make it more readable?

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you an other way to debug.
You can use a break point at this line and use the console to debug.

Once the break point stops the execution, in the console, write by example `po urlRequest` or `po urlRequest.debugDescription` to see your object.

Comment: Thanks, that should help